# Why is Poha allowed and Rice not allowed during Ekadashi?

Tags: vaishnavism, madhvacharya, ekadashi, madhwa

Rice is clearly not allowed in Ekadashi, but in Karnataka especially in Madhwa Sampradaya Poha or Avalakki is allowed.

But Poha is actually made up of Rice. How is this allowed?

Comment: Ideally, not allowed, but for those unable to fast, it is a relaxation of rule. Also, since poha/aval is a slightly milder form of puffed rice, it doesn't cause as much filling, or as much sleepiness. Even in the Sampradaya, if you say I want to keep full upavas, they will welcome it happily, they won't say you have to eat poha/aval.

Comment: @mar Yes but one can eat fruits if they can't do full fast. Why poha which is actually rice which should nit be eaten, it's like vreaking the whole fast isn't it?

Comment: like i said, poha, aval & upma are relaxations of rule for those unable to fast. even fruits might cause problems for sugar patients or those with acidity/ulcer, who need slow-release carbohydrates instead of fast-release glucose in fruits. this is not case just in madhwa sampradaya, even in tamilnadu mutt/ashrams, if you visit on ekadashi, they might give aval prasad

Comment: @mar excellent any scriptural background for this?